# Cannot relieve the rest assured response as String as length size is 323940. Please educate

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Cannot relieve the response as string as the string length is 323940 using rest assured java

Below are the code logic used:

```
System.out.println(responses.getBytes().length);
```

When I used the below logic console output will be display as blank screen

```
 // System.out.println(responses.toString());
```

Now, what is the right logic do I need to use here so that my Json to string length 323940 will be display. Please educate.

Thanks & Regards, Sailesh Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `Response` type to String

```
String res = response.asString();
```

To view response in pretty json format in console

```
response.prettyPrint();
```

Comment: This work well for me but  I could not view all the 300 recommendations in console.. What would I do?

Comment: I need to filter only SA Airlines from response so what logic would i implement here?

Comment: Where is your json? and what you want to get? Pls provide enough information to help people understand your problem.